# mongo map reduce returning incorrect counts for data sets of over 100 documents

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MapReduce results seem limited to 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318791/mapreduce-results-seem-limited-to-100)

I am having an issue with mongo mapreduce.

I have a document specified as

```
public class Response
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateGenerated { get; set; }
    public string ChallengeName { get; set; }
  }
```

I have added a number of documents to mongoDB all with the same ChallengeName.
I want to count the number of docs with the same challenge name. Seems simple...

I have produced the following map and reduce functions:

```
var map =
          "function() {emit(this.ChallengeName, 1);}";

var reduce =
       "function(key, values) {return values.length;}";
```

And I have set the options as follows:

```
MapReduceOptionsBuilder options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
options.SetOutput("output");
options.SetLimit(1000);
```

When I run the map reduce with under 100 documents the count returns the correct value, however when I run with 1000 documents the count returns with count = 101.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that is not wrong? There is an odd limit with geo queries but this is not one of them, also note that `limit` sets the input query not the output result limit, so if your first 1000 input documents only have 101 unique names then this is right. Edit: or maybe your problem is that it is not outputting the right count for each row? Here is a little cookbook tutorial on doing counting via MR: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Comment: I have 1000 responses with the same ChallengeName, so I would expect the count to be 1000. I have actually changed the reduce function to var reduce = "function(key, values) {return Array.sum(values);}"; which now works. However I am still at a loss why the previous version of the reduce function returns incorrect results

Comment: Ok I understand now. Change you reduce function to something like: `var reduce = function(values) {
    var count = 0;

    for (index in values) {
        count += values[index];
    }

    return count;
}` see if that helps first

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, that solution works. Have you any idea why function(key, values) {return values.length;} only works up to a 100 documents? This seems a widely used method of obtaining a count, so its a bit disconcerting

Comment: It is because of the way that an MR runs, I always get tongue tied when trying to explain this so the docs might be better but basically the reduce can run multiple times per document and must return something of the same shape as you input which means that what it actually returned as the total was the count of its last run, but the docs might explain better than me here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#troubleshoot-the-reduce-function (or not cos they took out the math part of the docs, hmm)

Comment: That makes sense. Its a shame that a lot of the examples online use the values.length method, it is pretty misleading, especially because it seems to work when the collection is small. Thanks for your help on this Sammaye you've been great.